# Yarn : yarn-default.xml location in hadoop-2.7.3

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We are trying to locate yarn-default.xml location in hadoop-2.7.3 could someone please point to where it may be located ......i'm able to find yarn-site.xml but not yarn-default.xml would greatly appreciate if someone could point out where it could be located.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the directory containing your hadoop installation navigate to
`share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common`.

As you should know, `yarn-default.xml` serves as the documentation for the default values, as compared to yarn-site.xml which represents your custom configuration values.

Comment: thanks for pointing out ....but i can change default values in yarn-default.xml if need to be right ? because my changes in yarn-site.xml are not taking effect ..could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575724/yarn-yarn-site-xml-changes-not-taking-effect

Comment: Yes, you can. I however recommend backing up the original default values before making any necessary changes so that if a failure might occur, you can use the original copy provided by hadoop instead.