# Yarn : Make yarn-site.xml changes effective on worker nodes in cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We have a spark streaming application running on HDFS 2.7.3 with Yarn as the resource manager. While running the application, these two folders:

```
  /tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/filecache
    /tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/filecache
```

are filling up and hence the disk. So from my research found that configuring these two properties in yarn-site.xml will help.

```
<property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms</name>
            <value>2000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
             <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb</name>
             <value>2048</value>
    </property>
```

I have configured them on yarn-site.xml on each namenode and masternode, and restarted the yarn on masternode using **stop-yarn.sh** **start-yarn.sh**. However still this doesn't seem to help. Am I missing anything while doing the configuration changes? And how can we make sure these changes are propagated to all worker nodes?

Comment: I posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575724/yarn-yarn-site-xml-changes-not-taking-effect/41578443#41578443 Did you try it?

Comment: i tried and replied back 2 days ago ..i also .put in Bold the update u probably missed it ..

Comment: Did you restart namenode services on each datanode?

Answer (score 0):

YARN workers are NodeManagers managed by the ResourceManager.  HDFS uses DataNodes and NameNode.  You have to restart YARN on all the hosts running NodeManagers in order for these changes to take effect.